# Create a smooth draggable bar-graph using d3js

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I am attempting to create a bar graph that can be updated by dragging the bars. I have been able to create such a graph but the dragging is not smooth. View my attempt in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p0rphda3/2/)

Here is my code:

```
var data = [{x:-6.1, y: "I"}, {x:-4.5, y: "H"}, {x: -0.4, y: "G"},{x:0.8, y: "F"}, {x:3.8, y: "E"}, {x: 5.3, y: "D"}];

drawDraggableBarGraph= function(data, drawSmoothCurve, element) {
  var bar, barHeight, datae, h, height, j, len, lineFunc, margin, objects, parsedX, svg, w, width, xAxis, xMax, xMin, xScale;
  $(element).empty();

  svg = d3.select(element).append("svg");

  margin = {
    top: 10,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 30,
    right: 10
  };

  w = $(element).width();
  h = 200;
  width = w - margin.left - margin.right;
  height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  for (j = 0, len = data.length; j < len; j++) {
    datae = data[j];
    parsedX = parseFloat(datae.x);
    datae.x = parsedX;
  }

  svg = svg.attr("width", w).attr("height", h).append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + margin.top + ")");

  xMin = d3.min(data, function(d) {
    return d.x;
  });
  xMax = d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.x;
  });

  xScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([xMin > 0 ? xMin * 0.95 : xMin * 1.05, xMax * 1.05]).range([0, width]);

  barHeight = (height / data.length) * 0.9;

  xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom").tickSize(-height);
  svg.append("g").attr("class", "x axis").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")").call(xAxis);

  objects = svg.append('svg').attr('width', width).attr('height', height);

  bar = objects.selectAll("g").data(data).enter().append("g").attr("transform",       function(d, i) {
    return "translate(0," + (i * barHeight + height * 0.05) + ")";
  }).attr('fill', function(d, i) {
    return d3.scale.category20().range()[i];
  });

  bar.append('rect').attr("x", 0).attr('width', width).attr('height', barHeight - 1).attr('fill', 'transparent');

  bar.append("rect").attr("x", function(d) {
    if (d.x > 0) {
      return xScale(0);
    } else {
      return xScale(d.x);
    }
  }).attr("width", function(d) {
    if (d.x > 0) {
      return xScale(d.x) - xScale(0);
    } else {
      return xScale(0) - xScale(d.x);
    }
  }).attr("height", barHeight - 1).attr('class', function(d) {
    return "drag-bar-" + d.y;
  });

  bar.on('mouseover', function(d) {
    jQuery("line.default-hidden").hide();
    return $(this).children('line').show();
  }).on('mouseout', function(d) {
    return jQuery("line.default-hidden").hide();
  });

  bar.append("text").attr("dy", ".75em").attr("y", barHeight / 2 - 7).attr("x", function(d) {
    if (d.x > 0) {
      return xScale(0) - 10;
    } else {
      return xScale(0) + 10;
    }
  }).attr("text-anchor", "middle").text(function(d) {
    return d.y;
  });

  if (drawSmoothCurve) {

    // Try commenting out from here 
    lineFunc = d3.svg.line().x(function(d) {
      return xScale(d.x);
    }).y((function(_this) {
      return function(d, i) {
        return i * barHeight + barHeight / 2 + height * 0.05;
      };
    })(this)).interpolate("basis");

    objects.append("path").attr("d", lineFunc(data)).attr("stroke", "#666666").attr("stroke-width", 1).attr("fill", "none");
    // Till here

    bar.append('line').attr('x1', function(d) {
      return xScale(d.x);
    }).attr('x2', function(d) {
      return xScale(d.x);
    }).attr('y1', -1).attr('y2', barHeight).attr('stroke', 'black').attr('stroke-width', '6').attr('class', function(d) {
      return "default-hidden drag-line-" + d.y;
    }).on("mousedown", function(d) {
      return d3.select(this).classed('drag-enabled', true);
    }).on('mousemove', function(d) {
      var newX, p;
      if ($(this).attr('class').indexOf('drag-enabled') < 0) {
        return;
      }
      p = d3.mouse(this);
      newX = p[0];
      return d3.select(this).attr('x1', newX).attr('x2', newX);
    }).on('mouseup', (function(_this) {
      return function(d) {
        var attrY, classList, k, klass, l, len1, len2, newBarX;
        d3.select(this).classed('drag-enabled', false);
        newBarX = d3.mouse(this)[0];
        classList = this.classList;
        attrY = null;
        for (k = 0, len1 = classList.length; k < len1; k++) {
          klass = classList[k];
          if (klass.indexOf('drag-line') >= 0) {
            attrY = klass.slice(klass.lastIndexOf('-') + 1);
          }
        }
        data = data;
        for (l = 0, len2 = data.length; l < len2; l++) {
          datae = data[l];
          if (datae.y === attrY) {
            datae.x = xScale.invert(newBarX).toFixed(2);
          }
        }
        return drawDraggableBarGraph(data, true,".sliding-bar");
      };
    })(this));
  }
}

drawDraggableBarGraph(data, true,".sliding-bar");
```

I am trying to make the process of updating values user-friendly but halts while dragging kills it somehow.

Any suggestions to make it smooth

Comment: Highcharts also has a draggable bar chart http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/3/Draggable-Points

Comment: I suggest moving your mouseMove and mouseUp code off of the element. Do a requestAnimationFrame(yourMouseMoveEvent) loop that always moved a stored/selected element. That element is set by your current mouseDown event and cleared on a global mouseUp event.

Comment: Thanks for the response. As per @GrahamPHeath suggestion, I moved the mouseMove and mouseUp code off the element and have attached those to the container 'svg' element. This seems to have made the graph smooth and user friendly. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p0rphda3/4/

GrahamPHeath: I don't get how requestAnimationFrame() help here.

Comment: RequestAnimationFrame would really be a nicety here, If you're interested, basically you replace the mouseMove code you have now with a looping requestAnimationFrame() call. see the example here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame but instead of moving the element to the left, you move the selected bar, if the mouse is down and there's a bar selected.